# what is function for calculating the total length of characters in C++

Tags: c++, xcode

I have question about function that calculate the total length of characters in C++. I found this function :

```
len = strlen(str1);
```

However, when I tried it in Xcode, Xcode gave me a yellow triangle which indicate something wrong or missing. see the picture below

[image]

So, could anyone help me to find the appropriate function for calculate total length ?

Comment: Change `len` to type `size_t`

Comment: This warning has nothing to do with `strlen` itself. It is about what you're doing with the result. `strlen` returns a value of type `std::size_t`. Assigning it to a variable of type `int` can potentially cause overflow (in the case of an extremely large string). You might overcome this warning by explicitly casting the value: `len = static_cast<int>(strlen(str1));`.

Comment: Note that `strcat(str1, str2);` invokes undefined behavoir because `str1` is not large enough to hold the result (the resulting string is 11 characters long, including the terminating zero).

Comment: As stated below ... you should really use a string class like std::string because it helps you to avoid buffer overruns like the one you create with "strcat(str1, str2)" - there you append a string of 5 characters to a string of 5 characters _and_ the terminating \0 - so in total you will have 11 characters living in a buffer of 10...

Comment: Please at least try to read and understand the diagnostic message before asking a question here.

Comment: Please, when you post a question (or answer), post the code, not a sreenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When strlen returns an unsigned long (size_t) your putting it into an int variable.  The first issue is that an unsigned long can be a very large number.  Much larger then an int. The second issue is that its unsigned, and the int is not. The length of your string cannot be negative, so it can safely be unsigned as well. Unsigned means that the last bit will not designate the negative or not negative status.

Example 1:

```
#include <iostream> //for cout
#include <cstring>   //for strlen()

using namespace std;  //so we don't have to type std:: all the time

int main(){
    char str1 = "Hello, World!";
    unsigned long myLength = strlen(str1); // size_t myLength = strlen(str1) would work
    cout << "String length: " << myLength << endl;
}
```

Example 2: (Use example 2 unless your doing an assignment that insists you use char arrays and strlen)

```
#include <iostream> //for cout
#include <string> 

using namespace std;  //so we don't have to type std:: all the time

int main(){
    string myString("Hello, World!");
    size_t myLength = myString.length(); // see length() in string, it also returns size_t
    cout << "String length: " << myLength << endl;
}
```

If you can, read up on variable signage and the stl typedefs (size_t is a typedef).  The doc page for string is a good place to check out what strings can offer you. [string - C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

Comment: There is no `strlen` in <string> it's in <cstring>

Answer (score 1):

Try the assigning like this

```
size_t len;
```

Instead of

```
int len;
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you try to call is declared in `cstring` (and `string.h`) so you need to

```
#include <cstring>
```

But if you use ObjectiveC++ use `std::string` class instead of `char` arrays.

Comment: Then it looks that you have a warning because you assign the result of `strlen`, which is unsigned, to `int` variable, which is signed. Use `size_t` instead of `int`.